# error probability of decision function

Tags: classification, bayesian, bayes-optimal-classifier

If I have a binary calssification task with prior probability $p(0) = 0.6$, and I make two decisions.

1) solely based on the prior probability  i.e. I make prediction 0 60% of the time and prediction 1 40% of the time.
2) always make the prediction 0.

As I can see, the error probability in both case is 0.4 right ?.  Why a constant decision rule and a rule based on prior gives same error ?

Comment: the error probability is not 0.4 in both cases.

Comment: @NikolasRieble can you elaborate it ?. How can i estimate the error probability then ?

Comment: your prediction is independent of the true target variable or any other information. Therefore, the error probability in the first case is 0.4 * 0.6 * 2 = 0.44, whereas the error probability in the second case is 0.4.

Comment: for your first case: What is the chance that you predict 0, whereas the correct value would be 1? (error A). What is the chance that you predict 1, whereas the correct value would be 0? (error B).

Comment: i think there is a typo, i think,  0.4*0.6*2 = 0.48

Comment: indeed, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on a comment, under scenario 1) you lose under two possibilities: 1) you randomly choose 0 and the truth was 1 or 2) you randomly choose 1 and the truth was 0. In both cases the probability is 0.4*0.6 and thus the total error probability is 0.4*0.6*2=0.48. Under scenario 2), you lose whenever the truth is 1 which occurs with probability 0.4.